# Flattening of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm performing data mining on images. Each pixel is treated as a data point. The image is read as follows:

```
im=Image.open('lena.bmp')
im=numpy.array(im)
print im.shape
```

Depending on whether the image is color or grayscale, im.shape is either (10,10, 3) or (10,10,1)

After that, the image is flattened to a feature matrix as follows:

if (10,10,3), then --->(100,3)

if (10,10,1), then --->(100,1)

How do I write a polymorphic function for this? My current approach is:

```
obs=reshape(im,(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1],1, im.size/(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1])))
```

Comment: Don't you have an extra 1 inside your shape tuple?

Comment: that's true. I'm having  obs=reshape(im,(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1], im.size/(im.shape[0]*im.shape[1])))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
obs = np.reshape(im, (-1, im.shape[-1]))
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this code? It works perfectly. shape[-1] is the number of dimensions, how about -1 before it?

Comment: @DzungNguyen `-1` is replaced internally by numpy to whatever value is needed to fit the size of the array.